# Maintaining counter value in PHP

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm working on a system where an android app needs to send periodic updates to a server to say it is running okay. If 4 checks pass and an update hasn't been sent, a text message needs to be sent. I want to use a counter in the PHP file that checks how many 'checks' have passed without an update. However every time the android application contacts the server the counter is reset and never increases. I have it working but I don't want the message to be sent until the counter is 4. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to retain the value of the counter when the file is 'reopened'. Thanks.

```
<?php  
//...
// check the value sent from the android application
if(isset($_REQUEST['alert'])){
  echo "alert";
  // everything is ok, reset the counter
  $counter = 0;
}
else echo "no alert";
// increase the counter
$counter++;

if($counter >= 4) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $phNum = $row['mobile'];        
}
// an update has not been sent in 4 attempts, send a text message
send_sms($phNum);
}
//...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could:
Use SharedPreferences in Android App which would keep count of checks? then send it to server to say all 4 checks were passed?

PHP script is executed from beginning every time you visit website, another method would be to use sessions but that will get a bit messy, and another way: when request is called, it would send your data + device ID (unique ID to each device), then it would add number of checks into database and keep track of checks for each device, that would slow down your execution time by not that much.

But as I said already, Shared Preferences would work.

Answer (score 0):

If your android app is properly sending and storing cookies you can use the php `$_SESSION` or `$_CCOKIE` variable for persistent data.